# STRING_URL not defined connecting to mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
  mongoose.connect(
  STRING_URL(
    'mongodb+srv://Edu:' +
      process.env.MONGO_ATLAS_PW +
      '@node-rest-shop.nzkxl.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
  ),

  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  }
);
```

console error:
ReferenceError: STRING_URL is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Remove the STRING_URL part as follows:

```
mongoose.connect(
  'mongodb+srv://Edu:' +
  process.env.MONGO_ATLAS_PW +
  '@node-rest-shop.nzkxl.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an advice, i recomend the use of template literals

```
mongoose.connect(
  `mongodb+srv://Edu:${process.env.MONGO_ATLAS_PW}
   @node-rest-shop.nzkxl.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
  {
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true
  }
);
```

Remenber you have to use `` backtips